# How do you set a search box to be initially empty?

Tags: html

Every time I open the home page to my site, the search box contains the contents from the previous search. Yet on almost every other web page these input fields are empty. I've looked into the source of a few websites and cannot find anything different to my own code. I don't beleive it's CSS related and I find it impossible to beleive that Javascript must be used. So how is it done? What am I missing?

```
<div id="search-bar">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="<?php _e("Search...") ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="special" value="" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you're storing the last search (like with a cookie), it should be blank. Please post your code. Also, do you have any browser add-ons that might be getting in the way?

Comment: Display snapshot of your code to be able to help you.

Comment: Is it possible that it's a browser feature (form auto-completion) that you've enabled for your specific site? Have you tried `autocomplete="off"`?

Comment: What's in the `value` attribute of the `input` tag in the HTML source?  `<input value="default search phrase"/>`

Comment: Try opening your page in Chrome in incognito mode (Cmd-Shift-N to open an incognito window) and see if it is still populated. If it is, we can troubleshoot that. If not, you know it's specific to your browser (likely a cookie).

Comment: Ok, cleared cookies solved it, now to find out where it's being set. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the placeholder bit:

```
placeholder="<?php _e("Search...") ?>"
```

Will be like this:

```
<input type="text" name="s" value="" />
```

Comment: I can't see if it changed anything because the previous term is still there. It's probably a cookie.

Comment: I've noticed that you found out there was a cookie populating the input. By removing the placeholder, it won't be filled up again, even with the cookie being set.